# Root view of SwiftUI app not showing expected `time ago` result

Tags: ios, swiftui, core-data

I'm working on a simple app where you can multiple journals, and each journal can have multiple entries. I have Core Data set up and working correctly, and a custom function to take each entry and format the date into a more readable format (taking cues from things like Instagram).

Here's the time formatting function:

```swift
func formatTimeAgo(_ date: Date) -> String {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let currentDate = Date()
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: date, to: currentDate)
    
    if let year = components.year, year > 0 {
        return "\(year) year\(year > 1 ? "s" : "") ago"
    } else if let month = components.month, month > 0 {
        return "\(month) month\(month > 1 ? "s" : "") ago"
    } else if let day = components.day, day > 0 {
        return "\(day) day\(day > 1 ? "s" : "") ago"
    } else if let hour = components.hour, hour > 0 {
        return "\(hour) hour\(hour > 1 ? "s" : "") ago"
    } else if let minute = components.minute, minute > 0 {
        return "\(minute) minute\(minute > 1 ? "s" : "") ago"
    } else {
        return "Just now"
    }
}
```

And I call it in my root (`Home`) and Entry page like so:

```swift
Text("\(formatTimeAgo(lastEntryDate))")
```

I've noticed that:

- The root view (`Home`) updates when I add a new Entry (as expected), but the time gets "stuck" on that time until I quit and relaunch the app, or change that Core Data entity in some way (delete an older entry or something).
- The Entry page always shows the correct time ago, for each entry, as expected.

I have a feeling this has something to do with how views are redrawn, but I can't figure out how to make sure that whenever I come back to the `Home` view (without leaving the app), I get the correct "time ago".

If it helps, here are the (simplified) home and entry views:

**Home view**

```swift
struct Home: View {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

  @FetchRequest(
    sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.updatedDate, order: .reverse)]
    ) var journals: FetchedResults<Journal>

  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(journals) { journal in
        NavigationLink {
          JournalDetailPage(journal: journal)
        } label: {
          JournalRowCell(journal: journal)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct JournalRowCell: View {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

  @ObservedObject var journal: Journal

  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      Text(journal.unwrappedName)

      if let lastEntryDate = journal.journalEntriesArray.first?.date {
        // While this correctly updates when a new Entry is added
        // to this journal (ie "Just now"), it will remain on "Just now"
        // until I quit and restart the app, or delete
        // one of the entries
        Text("\(formatTimeAgo(lastEntryDate))")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Journal detail view**

```swift
struct JournalDetailPage: View {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
  @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

  @ObservedObject var journal: Journal

  var body: some View {
    Stack {
      List {
        ForEach(journal.journalEntriesArray) { entry in
          VStack {
            Text(entry.unwrappedEntry)

            if let entryDate = entry.date {
              // Whenever I tap into this view, the date for each
              // entry shows the correct "time ago" value
              // this seems to be working perfectly
              Text("\(formatTimeAgo(entryDate))")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

###Update

I tried something which I was sure would work, but sadly no luck still.

```swift
struct JournalRowCell: View {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

  @ObservedObject var journal: Journal

  // NEW
  @State private var EntryUpdatedAt = Date()

  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      Text(journal.unwrappedName)

      if let lastEntryDate = journal.journalEntriesArray.first?.date {
        Text("\(formatTimeAgo(EntryUpdatedAt))")
      }
    }
    // NEW
    // I assumed setting this in state onAppear would
    // make it work when coming back to the view,
    // but unfortunately it's still not working
    // and if there are 50 journals, this feels like it would
    // be pretty expensive
    .onAppear {
      if let lastEntryDate = journal.journalEntriesArray.first?.date {
        EntryUpdatedAt = lastEntryDate
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want it to update, but you don't have an actual state that's getting updated, look at `TimelineView`

Comment: The reason your `EntryUpdatedAt` idea doesn't work is the `date` hasn't changed. You could change your strategy to update the `String` that you derive in `formatTimeAgo` on `onAppear`.

Comment: It's true the date hasn't changed, but the function to compare that date against right now should (a) run on appear and (b) show a different result (assuming more than 1 minute has passed) - or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: `EntryUpdatedAt` will not change if the `lastEntryDate` hasn't changed. So, if you just want your label to update, you need to set some state that _changes_. For example, the string that `formatTimeAgo` creates. Try that -- set your `@State` to a `String` and set it to the result of `formatTimeAgo`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [TimelineView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/timelineview), e.g.

```
TimelineView(.everyMinute) { timeline in
    Text("\(formatTimeAgo(entryDate))")
}
```

You should also use `@Environment(\.calendar) var calendar` to receive any changes to user makes to their calendar.

Unfortunately we can't use `Text(date, format: .relative)` for the past, since the date param doesn't change `Text's` `body` isn't called so it doesn't update. You could force with an `id` change but that gets ugly, e.g.

```
TimelineView(.everyMinute) { timeline in
    Text(entryDate, format: .relative)
        .id(timeline.date)
}
```